# How renew a ParseSession in Android SDK - Parse Server?

Tags: parse-platform

I`m using Parse Server, and I see that the ParseSession have a time of 1 year to expire/delete, I want to know how do renew a user's session using the Parse SDK for Android before it expires?

Comment: on server, delete the session. go back to client and delete the cookies . then your app should just prompt for a logon that will establish another 1 year session.    when the token lease expires at 1 year of age , it invalidates the session and you will get a session err that is mentioned in the docs. once you see what is reqd for a single user, you will see that you have an issue -- what to do about the cookie state on the client?  this value points to the old session and u can not drop/add it without orphaning the cookie value on the client.

Comment: what is bad with just letting them expire - cause invalid session errors accompany with prompt on client to log back in...

Comment: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#sessions   try updates on the "expiresAt" field .